# Forgotten Fried Eggs Recipe

Tags: eggs, fried-eggs

I have long been trying to increase the quality of my fried eggs. A few weeks ago I ran across a recipe that instructed me to crack the eggs into a cold pan, season them right there and THEN turn on the heat and cover them.

This turned out to be a great success and the eggs had amazing texture.

I thought I had kept that recipe however today I am unable to find it and I dont remember for how long and at what temperature it advised to cook them at.

I realize there are a lot of "amazing fried eggs" links out there but I am specifically looking for the one that involves covering the pan and seasoning the eggs while they are cold.

Does anyone fry their eggs like this?

Comment: It won't help for a recipe this old, but *before* you go trying a new search for a recipe you found fairly recently, check your browser's history.  Some of them will maintain weeks of history, so you just look for the last one that matches 'eggs' or whatever it was you were looking for.  (but they track when an item was last viewed, so if you search again, you risk marking it as being from today, not the day you first found it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I found the [recipe](https://www.framedcooks.com/2015/09/perfect-fried-eggs.html) that I'm assuming you were looking for? It seems to fit the description you've given.

From [framedcooks.com](https://www.framedcooks.com/2015/09/perfect-fried-eggs.html):

> 1. Pour the oil into a cold frying pan and swirl it around until the bottom is coated.
> 2. Crack the eggs carefully into the pan, keeping the yolks intact.
> 3. Sprinkle the salt and pepper over the eggs, along with the herbs and cheese if you are using those.
> 4. Cover the pan and turn the heat on to medium low. Cook for 6 minutes with no peeking! This will produce eggs with creamy runny yolks – leave them on for another minute or two if you like them more well done.
> 5. Run a knife between the eggs to separate them, slide them out of the pan onto plates and serve at once.

Enjoy your eggs.

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You found the exact article!

Comment: it's more like steamed than fry, no ? and the yolk will be covered by a white film instead of being fully yellow.

Comment: I use a similar technique, I fry my eggs  using butter, and near the end, I drop in a couple of tea spoon of water in the pan and cover for 10, 20 seconds.